# Rename Terraform template script

Tags: terraform

In the example below if I were to rename "script1.ps1" to a new name this would normally result in the destruction and recreation of server1.

```
data "template_file" "server1" {
    template = file("${path.module}/script1.ps1")
    vars = {}
}
```

Is it possible to update the script name without recreating the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can move it in state.

Something like:

```
terraform state mv template_file.server1 template_file.new_name
```

Once you move it in the terraform state, then you can rename it in the file.

```
data "template_file" "new_name" {
    template = file("${path.module}/script1.ps1")
    vars = {}
}
```

If you run `terraform plan` you shouldnt see any changes.

You will also need to update any references to the old name to point to the new name.

If you are using a version of terraform greater than 0.12 you might want to remove the data source template_file completly and replace it with a call to the [templatefile function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile).